# Inbox count for careers broken if you have unread, sent messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

If you have a message (specifically question on a job posting) you sent and marked as unread, you get the following:

[image]

All these do not update correctly (including Sent).

It seems that messages that are "sent" are added incorrectly into the "Inbox" categories. They then do not appear in those folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, that's a bug alright. The fix will go out to production in the next push which will be build 2934.

I can't see any reason to have the 'Mark as Unread' or 'Mark as Read' functionality for sent messages so the buttons are now hidden. I've also fixed the underlying bug which incorrectly updates the unread counts on the inbox too.

Thanks for the report!